# AWS Cloud directory: why am I getting the error when applying range for the listIndex request?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to get index items by range according to the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/clouddirectory/latest/developerguide/directory_objects_range_filters.html

Here is my request:

```
 array (
  'ConsistencyLevel' => 'EVENTUAL',
  'DirectoryArn' => 'myARN',
  'IndexReference' =>
  array (
    'Selector' => '/Global/fieldIndex',
  ),
  'RangesOnIndexedValues' =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'AttributeKey' =>
      array (
        'FacetName' => 'Field',
        'Name' => 'fieldPath',
        'SchemaArn' => 'myARNSCHEMA',
      ),
      'Range' =>
      array (
        'EndMode' => 'LAST',
        'StartMode' => 'INCLUSIVE',
        'StartValue' =>
        array (
          'StringValue' => 'deal.applications.applicants',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

And I have the error response:

```
Limited range must be the first range after prefixes

'[range[<FIRST>, <LAST>], range[precedes{6465616c2e6170706c69636174696f6e732e6170706c6963616e7473}, <LAST>]]' -

{"Message":"Limited range must be the first range after prefixes '[range[<FIRST>, <LAST>], range[precedes{6465616c2e6170706c69636174696f6e732e6170706c6963616e7473}, <LAST>]]'"}
```

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this in another way changing the request:

```
array (
  'ConsistencyLevel' => 'EVENTUAL',
  'DirectoryArn' => 'arn',
  'IndexReference' => 
  array (
    'Selector' => '/Global/fieldIndex',
  ),
  'RangesOnIndexedValues' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'AttributeKey' => 
      array (
        'FacetName' => 'Field',
        'Name' => 'fieldPath',
        'SchemaArn' => 'schmaarn',
      ),
      'Range' => 
      array (
        'EndMode' => 'EXCLUSIVE',
        'StartMode' => 'INCLUSIVE',
        'StartValue' => 
        array (
          'StringValue' => 'Global.deal.applications.applicants.',
        ),
        'EndValue' => 
        array (
          'StringValue' => 'Global.deal.applications.applicants/',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```